# TensorFlow estimator vs train

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow seems to have two different APIs for actually running an optimization process, that is, I've seen two different families of sample code, one of which looks like

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)
```

and the other of which looks like

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

They are genuine alternatives; each sample program uses one or the other but not both.

Which of these should be used? Has one been deprecated in favor of the other? Is one intended for simple cases and the other for more complex cases?

Comment: These are simply two different methods of approximating some measure of "best fit" solution.  Read about the two methods; they're covered quite well in the machine-learning literature on line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow offers APIs at several different levels of abstraction, and by using a more high-level API you are buying convenience and ease of development/experimentation at the cost of flexibility: Your first example saves you the trouble of explicitly specifying a `cost`, which is the squared error by default for `LinearRegressor`. However, you may quickly find yourself in situations, where the options for `LinearRegressor` don't quite cut it; for example, you may have dependencies in your sample that force you to use manually specify another cost function, and in that case you would drop down a layer, and use the less abstract API.

In practice, it may easily pay off to know the different versions, allowing yourself to drop in at the proper level of abstraction for the problem you are trying to solve.

Another example of a high-level API to TensorFlow is [Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras).

Answer (score 1):

These two things aren't really comparable

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)
```

is a high level abstraction which creates a linear regressor (including its own optimizer which you can set in the constructor)

while,

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

defines no model architecture, simply the optimization method to be used on a given model.

If you wanted to you could instantiate a LinearRegressor with a GradientDescentOptimizer as the optimizer by specifying `optimizer="SGD"` in the parameters, otherwise it defaults to `optimizer="Ftrl"`

If you want a more detailed breakdown of the example code that confused you you'll have to reference exactly what it is.